# C++ Wrting a function that returns the number of occurrences of the characters 'a','e', 'i' from the string called line_of_input

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to make a program that uses a function to count the occurrence of "a", "e", "i" vowels within a string by using an array.

This is the code I have come up so far. I have no idea where to place the function in their proper order. Please give me some guidance. I think the declaration of `n` is wrong.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

struct N{
    int n1;
    int n2;
    int n3;
};
N check(string line_of_input[],N n);
// 

int main()
{
    int n={n,n,n};
    string line_of_input="you are idiot";
    check(line_of_input,n);
    cout<<n.n1<<endl;
    cout<<n.n2<<endl;
    cout<<n.n3<<endl;
}

Data count_aei(string sentence)
{
    Data count =0;

    for(int i=0,i<sentencesize(),i++)
    {
        if(sentence[i]=='a') count.na++;
        if(sentence[i]=='e') count.ne++;
        if(sentence[i]=='u') count.nu++;
    }
    return count;
}

N check(string line_of_input[],N n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<line_of_input.size();i++)
    {
        if(line_of_input[i]=='a')
        n.n1++;
        if(line_of_input[e]=='a')
        n.n2++;
        if(line_of_input[o]=='a')
        n.n3++;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: lol @ "you are idiot"

Answer (score 0):

Function check() should return an N, but it does not need to be passed in an N. Also, it is working on one string, not an array of them:

```
N check(string line_of_input)
{
    N n = {0, 0, 0};
    for(int i=0;i<line_of_input.size();i++)
    {
        if(line_of_input[i]=='a')
        n.n1++;
        if(line_of_input[i]=='e')
        n.n2++;
        if(line_of_input[i]=='i')
        n.n3++;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Also, I fixed a bug in your checks. 'i' goes in the square brackets in each case, because it represents your loop iterator variable used in the `for` loop; the letter you are looking for goes in the single quotes.

Then you can catch the returned N in main:

```
int main()
{
    string line_of_input="you are idiot";
    N n = check(line_of_input);
    cout<<n.n1<<endl;
    cout<<n.n2<<endl;
    cout<<n.n3<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You didn't catch that the argument to `check` is a `string[]` which is certainly wrong

Comment: Thanks! Fixed. Feel free to edit my answer if you find any other errors. This code could definitely still use some cleanup, but it should at least function as desired in its current state.

Comment: Yep it probably should